# Beginner String Array Manipulation

Tags: java, arrays, string, intellij-idea

I am having trouble with one of my assignments. I completed the code and have to submit the assignment that will auto grade it using a bunch of tests. I got all but two of them to pass. I don't know the code for the tests. I am assuming it's coming from this method:

```
/**
 * _Part 2: Implement this method._
 *
 * @return the number of items in the list.
 */
public int size() {
    int size = 0;       //int holder for size of elements in array
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++){     //loop to run through up to length of array
        if(array[i] != null){           //if data at array index has a value, increase int size
            size++;
        }
        else{           //if data at array index has no value, there are not anymore elements to check for
            break;
        }
    }
    return size;        //returning the number of elements in the array
}
```

These are the errors I am getting:

```
Starting: insertTwoItems
Failed: insertTwoItems
 Hint: Size should be 2 after two inserts! expected:<2> but was:<1>
Finished: insertTwoItems

Starting: insertThreeItems
Failed: insertThreeItems
 Hint: Size should be 2 after two inserts! expected:<2> but was:<1>
Finished: insertThreeItems
```

The constructor is simply: array = new String[10];

This is how I insert new strings into the array

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
/**
 * _Part 1: Implement this method._
 *
 * Inserts a new item in the OrderedArrayList. This method should ensure
 * that the list can hold the new item, and grow the backing array if
 * necessary. If the backing array must grow to accommodate the new item, it
 * should grow by a factor of 2. The new item should be placed in sorted
 * order using insertion sort. Note that the new item should be placed
 * *after* any other equivalent items that are already in the list.
 *
 * @return the index at which the item was placed.
 */
public int insert(String item) {
    if(array.length <= size()){         //checking if string array is full
        String[] tempArray = array;     //creating a temp string array, to make this.array bigger
        array = new String[array.length*2];     //doubling the length of array

        for(int i = 0; i < tempArray.length; i++){      //putting tempArray values back into original array
            array[i] = tempArray[i];
        }
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < array.length; i++){      //loop to find location to add item into
        if(array[i] == null){       //if array index location is null, then put item in that spot.
            array[i] = item;
            return i;               //returning index location item was put at
        }
        if(item.compareTo(array[i]) < 0){       //will only insert until array index is alphabetically smaller than item
            for(int j = size()-1; j > i; j--){      //moving all items from array size down to index j
                array[j+1] = array[j];          //copying left index into right index

            }
            array[i] = item;        //once all indexes from where item should go is moved to the right, index is put in the array
            return i;               //returning index of array where item went
        }
    }

    return 1000000;     //not necessary, but cannot compile without a return outside of loops. Should not reach this
}
```

I am not sure what the suppression warning is for either. Does anyone see any errors in my code that might affect the tests shown above to fail?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is from this part.

```
for(int j = size()-1; j > i; j--){      //moving all items from array size down to index j   
    array[j+1] = array[j];             //copying left index into right index
}
```

The assignment of `j` is incorrect. Since for example you have an array `['a','z']` and you are about to insert `'c'`. `j` will have the value of 1 and the value of your `i` is also 1 thus it will not go inside the loop. You should change it to this.

```
for (int j = size(); j >= i; j--) { // moving all items from array size down to index j
    array[j] = array[j - 1]; // copying left index into right index
}
```

Now the value of `j` will be 2 and the value of `i` is 1 thus it will go inside your loop. You then do the copying of left index into right index.

Also regarding this.

```
return 1000000;
```

This is actually needed but your return must be `-1`. Returning `-1` means that the item was not inserted since `-1` is not a valid index in an array.